# Записать из массива А[length] в массив B[length] позиции всех элементов, дробная часть которых содержит два знака(т.е. например 15,25)

Tags: c++, c

```
double arr_4[length];
double arr_result_4[length];
double x = 0, y = 0;
int basic;
cout << "Задача 4. \n";
//Ниже идет заполнение массива дробными числами(в пределах трех знаков)
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    x = rand() % 50;
    y =  rand() % 900;
    if (y > 100) {
        y /= 1000;
    } else {
        y /= 100;
    }
    arr_4[i] = x + y;
    cout << arr_4[i] << " ";
}
cout << "\n";
//Здесь пытаюсь вычленить элементы
cout << "Итоговый массив: \n";
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    basic = arr_4[i] * 1000;
    if ((basic%1000) > 100) {
        basic %= 1000;
    } else {
        basic %= 100;
    }
    if (basic > 10 && basic < 99) {
        arr_result_4[i] = arr_4[i] ;
        cout << arr_result_4[i] << " ";
    }
}
cout << "\n";
```

Comment: А Вас не смущает, что большинство вещественных чисел не могут быть точно представлены ограниченным числом цифр?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, о чем вы спрашиваете. Если можете помочь, напишите пример.

Comment: Сколько знаков в дробной части у `0.1`? Один? Однако это число хранится в double примерно как `0.1000000000000000055511`. Поэтому задача поставлена некорректно.

Comment: Чтобы задача была корректной, вам надо хранить дробные части как целочисленные добавки к их целым частям. Так правильно, например, работать с *деньгами*.

Comment: А как вообще такую задачу решать в C\C++,  как понимаю здесь нет типа с точным дробным (как decimal в C#)? Но зато можно создать свой тип, используя asm вставки? (самому интересен этот вопрос). Кто знает.